# Poles of $\frac{\sin z}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, proof-verification

I need to find the poles of the following function $$f(z) = \frac{\sin z}{z}$$

However, as ${z \rightarrow 0 }$,  $f(z) \rightarrow 1$. So, I think I should rule out $z = 0 $ case. But I am not able to see any other pole of this function.

Please correct me if I am wrong about $z=0$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no pole in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$

To see this, write $$\sin z=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}+\cdots$$
which implies $$\frac{\sin z}{z}=1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}+\cdots$$

Comment: no pole in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ means that there could be a pole at $z=0$ ..

Comment: @user1952009 I believe we are all on the same page of agreeing there is no pole at $z=0$, so I ignored it :)

Comment: so you meant that the power series for $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ is entire

Answer (score 4):

You are correct: $0$ is a removable singularity, not a pole. And there are no other candidates, so there are no poles.

Comment: So in that case we can not calculate the integral of $f(z)$ using residue theorem?

Comment: Sure you can. There are no residues so integrating $f(z)$ over any closed contour gives you zero.

Comment: @Dark_Knight if you meant computing say $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x} e^{i a x} dx$ with the residue theorem : yes it will be complicated, you'll probably need a "trick"