# What type of singularity is $z=1$ for $f(z)=\frac{z^{4}(z-1)^{2}}{\sin^{2}(\pi z)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Im trying to figure out what type of singularity $z=1$ is for the function $f(z)=\frac{z^{4}(z-1)^{2}}{\sin^{2}(\pi z)}$.

In my solution manual it says that it is a pole of order 1 but Im trying to understand how they come to this conclusion.

If I set that
\begin{align*}
f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{z-1},
\end{align*}
which means that $g(z)=(z-1)f(z)$ and $g$ is holomorphic in the neighborhood of $z=1$. We have that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\to 1}g(z)=\lim_{z\to 1}(z-1)f(z)=\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{(z-1)^{3}}{\sin^{2}(\pi z)}= 0.
\end{align*}
But since $g(1)=0$ then $f$ do NOT have a pole at $z=1$? It seems like $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=1$ not a pole of order 1.

Can someone help me? Is it correct that $z=1$ is a pole of order 1 to $f$? If so, then how?

Comment: I think your conclusion is right - $f$ has a removable singularity at $z = 0$.

Comment: But my question was for $z=1$ not $z=0$. I know that $f$ has a removabble singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean $ z = 1$. That was a typo.

Comment: I even double checked the Laurent series on Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

One of [the Riemann's theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) concerning removable singularities states it needs to be $$\lim_{z\rightarrow1}(z-1)f(z)=0$$ 
And, just to be sure the calculations are right [using this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744525/poles-of-frac-sin-zz):
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow1}(z-1)f(z)=\lim_{z\rightarrow1}\frac{z^4(z-1)^3}{\sin^2{(\pi z)}}=\lim_{z\rightarrow1}\frac{z^4(\pi z-\pi)^3}{\pi^3 \sin^3{(\pi z-\pi)}}\cdot \frac{\sin^3{(\pi z-\pi)}}{\sin^2{(\pi z)}}=\\
\frac{1}{\pi^3}\lim_{z\rightarrow1}\frac{\sin^3{(\pi z-\pi)}}{\sin^2{(\pi z)}}=\frac{1}{\pi^3}\lim_{z\rightarrow1}\frac{\left(\sin{\pi z \cos{\pi} - \cos{\pi z} \sin{\pi}}\right)^3}{\sin^2{(\pi z)}}=\frac{-1}{\pi^3}\lim_{z\rightarrow1}\sin{\pi z}=0$$